# Calling Identity column without inserting any data from source

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with Identity column set on ID
Ex:

```
Create table Customer
(
  ID Int identity (1,1),
  FirstName varchar(20),
  PhNumber int,
)
```

I have a table on other database which populates this table 
So I wrote something like

```
Create or alter view abcCustomer 
As 
Select 
  ?  as ID
  Fname as FirstName,
  Pnumber as phnumber
From dbo.Scustomer (this is my table in source)
```

Here we are creating ID column in target only but not sure how to call or what to call from source so that it doesn’t affect the AbcCustomer View and populate identity records in target table and also the FirstName and phNumber from the source table.

Could anyone help what should I write in place of `?` In order to get my table populated as identity column, because unless and until we call the ID column from the source it’s gonna end up with having errors.

Comment: `I have a table with Identity column` ... then right away you're not actually using MySQL.  Please remove all database tags and then tag with the database you are really using here.

Comment: well, you want to fetch only id from the target table into the source table, right?

Comment: Good day @Rana, I am not sure I understood what you need. Do you mean that you want to find the ID which fit the Fname and Pnumber values? if this is the case and these columns (together or one of them) are not unique then you cannot, since there might be multiple rows that fit these values. Usually the Identity column is the way to find the rows and not vise versa. It might help if you can elaborate a bit more including why you try/need this solution - maybe we can find a totally different solution for your source needs.

Answer (score 0):

there are so many ways to get id and others data from source table!

1. Using Where condition (you can use stored procedure):

   ```
      Declare @i as int = 1
      Select Id, FName, PhNumber From dbo.SCustomer Where Id = @i
      set @i = @i+1
   ```
2. Using Offset:

   ```
    Declare @i as int = 1
    Select Id, FName, PhNumber from Dbo.Sccustomer Order By Id Offset @i Rows Fetch 
    Next @i Rows Only
    Set @i = @i+1
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert data from the source customer table to target customer table then you should write a query in this way -

Option 1  - If you want to use the identity same as in the source table then Turn on the identity so that you will be able to insert value in the identify column (refer below query)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Customer ON

Insert Customer
(ID, FirstName, PhNumber)
Select 
  ID  as ID
  Fname as FirstName,
  Pnumber as phnumber
From dbo.Scustomer

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Employee  OFF

Option 2 - If you want to generate the new identity in the  source table then use the below query.

Insert Customer
(FirstName, PhNumber)
Select 
  Fname as FirstName,
  Pnumber as phnumber
From dbo.Scustomer